# Use user input to select sub directory

Tags: r

I have a directory with multiple sub-directories within them and I did like to list the sub-directories then let the user choose the sub-directory he wants to read files within it.

I want the use to use the index to input his selection before the code continues to read files inside. Here is what I tried to list all sub-directories within the parent directory but I am stuck at how to use user raw input to select a sub-directory before reading the files within:

```
path = setwd("path to parent directory")

sub_dirs <- list.dirs(path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

#User raw input to be used here before listing files within
.....

#list all files
files <- dir(path, pattern = '\\.csv', full.names = FALSE)

#read files
tables <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

Expected output is a code where I can list sub-directories within the parent directory then allow a user to input an index of the sub-directory he wants to read files inside it. then after user input then code proceeds to list csv files inside then read the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prompt the user to select a subdirectory with `menu(choices = sub_dirs)`.

Comment: I am getting this error  Error in dir(menu(choices = sub_dirs), pattern = "/.csv", full.names = FALSE) : 
  invalid 'path' argument

Comment: `menu()` returns the index of the chosen option, not the value. So in the case you describe you'd probably want `sub_dirs[menu(choices = sub_dirs)]`.

Comment: this works fine, just a question, Can I be able to change message that appears before selection? and  how can I make that after select it proceeds with running the code not to ask me for selection again after I have chosen something

Comment: You can use the `title` argument in `menu()` to control the message. As for not asking again, I think you could save the choice in a variable that's initially set to `NULL`, set it when you first ask for a selection, and then always check if the choice is already set before asking again.

Answer (score 0):

`tcltk` is a base R package. `tk_choose.dir` will open a modal dialog window for a user to select a folder:

```r
tcltk::tk_choose.dir(default = "~/")
```